# increasing row width

Tags: multicol, multirow

I have used a multicolumn(with 2 columns). But in one column when the line ends, the things are not visible.Like this on first row [image: the wrong one]

I want that as follows [image: correct one]

My code for this segment is

```
\section{Technical Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}    
\textsc{Techniques Acquainted with:} & Machine Learning, Sentiment Analysis, Data Retrieval, Web Scrapping, Database Management,Working with APIs(REST, OAuth 2), Research paper Writing \\

\textsc{General Programming:} & Java ,C++ ,C ,R ,Python , NLTK, PHP ,Shell Scripting ,HTML ,SQL\\

\textsc{Other Software:} & JFlap ,Anaconda ,Matlab ,Octave ,R Studio ,Android Studio ,Eclipse ,Netbeans ,MySQL ,MS office \\

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet as small complete document (Minimal Working Example) which can we copy and compile in our computers. Help us to help you.

Comment: for broke lines in cel into more lines you need to use different table environment and column type, for example: `\begin{tabularx}{rX}` can help you

Comment: @Zarko I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Zarko tabularx not working properly.

Comment: It should work. If you will consider my first comment and accordingly edit your question, I will make answer in which I will show you how to properly use `tabularx`. Do you load `tabularx` package?

Comment: @Zarko question edited. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zarko said, `tabularx` works, if you don't forget to specify the total width of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\sffamily\Large\scshape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Technical Skills}%
\vspace*{-2ex}\hrule\vspace*{2ex}
\sffamily
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rX@{}}
  \textsc{Techniques Acquainted with:} & Machine Learning, Sentiment Analysis, Data Retrieval, Web Scrapping, Database Management,Working with APIs(REST, OAuth 2), Research paper Writing \\

  \textsc{General Programming:} & Java, C++, C, R, Python, NLTK, PHP, Shell Scripting, HTML, SQL \\
  \textsc{Other Software:} & JFlap, Anaconda, Matlab, Octave, R Studio, Android Studio, Eclipse, Netbeans, MySQL, MS office \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.

Comment: @Zarko: note I made due credits. I began working on the details (sans font and correct spacing for commas) before you proposed to post an answer, and didn't think of looking at new comments.